# MAMPRO 3 How to disable fastcgi completely

Tags: magento, soap, mamp, mamp-pro

> [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>
> [notice] Digest: done
>
> [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 7906)
>
> [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_ssl/2.2.29
>   OpenSSL/0.9.8zd mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0
>   configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: comm with server
>   "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.6.7.fcgi" aborted: error parsing
>   headers: duplicate header 'Content-Type'

I disabled the cgi stuff from the gui. See picture below;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Additional note: if you're running multiple hosts in MAMP Pro, make sure that you have PHP set to use the “module” option, not the CGI option. Otherwise NONE of the other CGI changes will make any difference.